# Autolayout not adding gap vertically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am a newbie figuring out autolayout programmatically.

i defined a imageview ,added to superview (UIViewController). added constraints using visual format to set gap . i haven't provided value just dash (-) . As per resource iam referring to learn, without providing value i will get 8pts gap.

I get gap horizontally but not vertically.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
UIImageView * thumbnailImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
thumbnailImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbnailImage"];
thumbnailImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
thumbnailImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
thumbnailImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

[self.view addSubview:thumbnailImageView];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[thumbnailImageView]-|" options:0
                      metrics:nil
                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(thumbnailImageView)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[thumbnailImageView]-|" options:0
                           metrics:nil
                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(thumbnailImageView)]];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the margins to always be used, you need to set: `self.view.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = YES;`

Alternatively, you can also change the margins as well:

```
self.view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8);
self.view.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = YES;
```

Otherwise the view will grow or shrink accordingly in order to fit. When you add the above lines of code, you will notice that it adds the 8 pixels by default for you to all constraints. However, the horizontal constraints might now look larger or seem like it is 16.. This is because margins can be 8, 16, or 20.

It is always better to specify your sizes explicitly.